# Conditionally copy a template in XSLT 1.0 (Optimizing call templates )

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to optimize my code,

I use my xslt code for 2 kind of input, I classify the input /output by "Typology". Typology can be `=1` or `=2`.

Since the output are quite similar, its basically the same file except for 1 extra element `<Extension>`

I don't want to keep "Extension1" and "Extension2" in the same `xsl`. I would like to use **one** Extension for both typologies.

Before continue, in my original code Extensions have **significantly** more "elements" and is based on more than 2 conditions.

```
                               <!--templates-->
    <xsl:template name = "Header">
            <xsl:param name = "VariableMessage" />
            <xsl:param name = "VariableTime" />
            <Header>
                <MessageID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$VariableMessage"/>
                </MessageID>
                <GeneratedTime>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$VariableTime"/>
                </GeneratedTime>
            </Header>
        </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name = "Extension1" >
            <Tags>
                <Area>ABC</TArea>
                <Group>XYZ</Group>
                <Extensions>
                    <Extension>
                        <ExtName>CALCULATION</ExtName>
                        <ExtValue datatype="String">Owner</ExtValue>
                    </Extension>
                    <Extension>
                        <ExtName>GROUP</ExtName>
                        <ExtValue datatype="String">XYZ</ExtValue>
                    </Extension>
              </Extensions>
          </Tags>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name = "Extension2" >
            <Tags>
                <Area>ABC</TArea>
                <Group>XYZ</Group>
                <Extensions>
                    <Extension>
                        <ExtName>CALCULATION</ExtName>
                        <ExtValue datatype="String">Owner</ExtValue>
                    </Extension>
              </Extensions>
          </Tags>
</xsl:template>
                
                            <!--close templates-->
```

Now, my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                            <!--variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="typology" select="//typology"/>
    <xsl:variable name="VariableMessage" select="//VariableMessage"/>
    <xsl:variable name="VariableTime" select="//VariableTime"/>


                 <!--parameters for a call-template-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="Header">
            <xsl:with-param name="VariableMessage" select = "$VariableMessage"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="VariableTime select = "$VariableTime"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
                                            


                         <!--/Extensions/-->
           <!--depends in the Typology: can be either 1 or 2-->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$typology='1'">
                <xsl:call-template name="Extensions1"></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="Extensions2"></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can I use something like, making sure I'm copying "Extension"
**How can I specify "Copy" elements for this specific template + based on a condition**

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Seems you need a way to pass a function (template) as a parameter. In XSLT 1.0 this was done nearly 20 years ago. Read this:  http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I haven´t voted yet due none of these answer solve my problem. I was expecting to have more options. I was trying to improve the code, adding a IF statement as you pointed below will just add more lines, now into the  main template (I have more than 2 Extensions elements). I will accept  your answer you have spent time on this, appreciate your solution and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to follow without seeing an example of the input and the expected output. AFAICT, you could use something like:

```
<xsl:template name="Extension">
    <Tags>
        <Area>ABC</TArea>
        <Group>XYZ</Group>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <ExtName>CALCULATION</ExtName>
                <ExtValue datatype="String">Owner</ExtValue>
            </Extension>
            <xsl:if test="$typology=1">
                <Extension>
                    <ExtName>GROUP</ExtName>
                    <ExtValue datatype="String">XYZ</ExtValue>
                </Extension>
            </xsl:if>
        </Extensions>
    </Tags>
</xsl:template>
```

Don't see what copying a template has to do with this.

Also not sure why you need those named templates. Seems like you could do it all in the main template, without the added complexity.